# How to get the bomb flower past the ice turret in Lorule Castle

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I’m stuck trying to get past the bomb room in Lorule Castle (the top-left room on the third floor). I have to get the big bomb flower to the boulder, but the ice turret keeps on hitting the bomb flower. Can you please tell me how to get past this?

Comment: Which floor & map area is this puzzle on?

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of the place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as shielding the turret’s shots, or just dodging with good timing, you can use the Ice Rod on the turret to stop it from shooting for a few seconds.

1. Stand out of the way of the ice turret.
2. Merge into and out of a wall to stop the bomb flower from following you.
3. Approach the ice turret and use the the Ice Rod on it. It will turn blue and stop shooting for a few seconds.
4. Run back and tell the bomb to follow you again.
5. While the ice turret is still frozen, run to the boulder, then attack the bomb to start its fuse.

Answer (score 2):

The turret shoots every couple of seconds. You can defend the bomb using your Hylian Shield and use the time between shots to place it close to the boulder, then hit it and get away.